# Evaluating $K\big(\frac{3-\sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{2}}\big)$

Tags: gamma-function, elliptic-integrals, singular-values

On MSE, I have seen derivations of the elliptic integral special values
$$K(1/\sqrt{2})=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/4)}{4\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$K(\tan(\pi/8))=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} +1} \Gamma (1/8)\Gamma (3/8)}{2^{13/4}\sqrt{\pi}}$$ $$K(\sin(\pi/12))=\frac{3^{1/4}\Gamma ^{3}(1/3)}{2^{7/3}\pi}$$
...but how can one prove the following identity?

$$K\big(\frac{3-\sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{2}}\big)=\frac{\Gamma(1/7)\Gamma(2/7)\Gamma(4/7)}{\sqrt[4]{7}\cdot 4\pi}$$

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391229/72031

Answer (score 4):

Since $1,2,4$ are the quadratic residues $\!\!\pmod{7}$, one way to prove such identity is to recall the [Chowla-Selberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chowla%E2%80%93Selberg_formula) and the relations between the Dedekind $\eta$ function and the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: That formula looks like Swahili to me. I was hoping to find a proof that didn't use such advanced machinery, but instead integral manipulations.

Comment: @Frpzzd: [according to Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html), the RHS is simply related to $B\left(\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7}\right)$, so an integral approach boils down to finding the correct transformations to turn $\int_{0}^{1}x^{-6/7}(1-x)^{-5/7}\,dx$ into a multiple of a complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: Something similar but simpler is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1631760/44121).

Comment: The given $k=\mathfrak{f}_2^4/\mathfrak{f}^4$ value corresponds to $\tau=\sqrt{-7}$; an example of the Chowla-Selberg formula for that value of $\tau$ is given [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979205/). You can figure out the value for $\mathfrak{f}^4\eta^2$ from those and use $K=\frac{\pi}{2}\theta_3^2=\frac{\pi}{2}\mathfrak{f}^4\eta^2$.

Comment: @Frpzzd: I don't think there is any elementary evaluation of $K(k_n) $ apart from $n=1,2,3$. Looks like some mysteries of elliptic integrals can't be handled via calculus alone and unfortunately one does need some algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is an elementry approach.
We know that
$$
K\left(\frac{3-\sqrt7}{4\sqrt2}\right)=\sqrt[4]7\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dz}{\sqrt{z^4+21z^2+112}}
$$
This was explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3047839).
Then with the substitution
$$
z=\frac{2 \left(x^2 \left(x^7+1\right)^{3/7}-\left(x^7+1\right)^{2/7}-x^3\right)}{x \left(x^7+1\right)^{1/7} \sqrt{\left(x^7+1\right)^{3/7}+x^3 \left(x^7+1\right)^{1/7}-x}}
$$
we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dz}{\sqrt{z^4+21z^2+112}}
=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\left(x^7+1\right)^{3/7}+x^3 \left(x^7+1\right)^{1/7}-x}{2 \left(x^7+1\right)^{6/7}}\mathrm dx
$$
Now we can evaluate it with beta integral.

Comment: +1 there. Your evaluations of elliptic integrals are based on mysterious substitutions, but it appears that deep down they are based on the transformation theory of elliptic integrals given by Jacobi. It would be nice to have some explanation / remarks regarding the substitutions used.

Comment: How did you obtained this substitution, did you used a computer?