# Integral $\int_{\sqrt{33}}^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-11x^2+11x+121}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

> How can we prove $$I:=\int_{\sqrt{33}}^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-11x^2+11x+121}}\\=\frac1{6\sqrt2\pi^2}\Gamma(1/11)\Gamma(3/11)\Gamma(4/11)\Gamma(5/11)\Gamma(9/11)?$$

**Thoughts of this integral**
This integral is in the form $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{P(x)}}dx,$$where $\deg P=3$. Therefore, this integral is an elliptic integral.
Also, I believe this integral is strongly related to Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp(u)$. In order to find $g_2$ and $g_3$, substitute $x=t+11/3$ to get $$I=2\int_{\sqrt{33}-11/3}^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4t^3-352/3t+6776/27}}$$
The question boils down to finding $\wp(I;352/3,-6776/27)$ but I seem to be on the wrong track.

Comment: I see a product of gamma values, probably the Beta function of Euler is used. Maybe it's better to prove the formula from right to left. (I don't have a solution)

Comment: Possibly useful is a google search for ["products of gamma functions" + "elliptic integrals"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22products+of+gamma+functions%22+%22elliptic+Integrals%22).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html

Comment: see something similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2407578/515527

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2391675/72031

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Zacky’s comment it suffices to turn the cubic denominator into a quadratic one, then perform the Landen transform to come to an elliptic integral of the first kind equivalent to K(k11)_
fjaclot